# Limit with n as a power

Tags: limits

Find the limit  when n tends to infinity of the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline: Let $1/n=t$. Using your idea, we first want to find the limit as $t$ approaches $0$ from the right of 
$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+2^t}{2}\right)}{t}.$$ L'Hospital's Rule will work nicely for this.

The limit originally asked for will turn out to be $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Hi im very curious as to why the limit must suddenly be seen as approach 0

Comment: Because $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$

Comment: We transfer the $n$ on top to the bottom, where it becomes $1/n$. Now for applying L'Hospital's Rule, it is convenient to call this $t$. Not necessary, in fact, but it makes things simpler.

Comment: You are welcome. Good to hear.